# IPhone Segmented Control Tapping

Tags: objective-c, view, uisegmentedcontrol, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

Is it allowed to **switch to different screens** (like popViewController / pushViewController) when we tap the segments of segmented control? or **do we have to stay in the same screen and change the views**?

Comment: like? a bit more information would help.

Comment: I need to change the screen on tapping because client requires **back navigation** in particular format like..(if my segment control has segments named x and y. If i tap x->y->x->y back navigation should be in reverse order like y->x->y->x.For this i need to use **PushViewController**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your requirement. But it is not a good practice to push view using a segmented control. Segmented should work like switch. For Example a tableView which display data according to segment selection.

Comment: @Deepak thanks. By the way I had sent you a mail few days ago. Have you seen that mail?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not disallowed but really if you are looking for a page control like behavior navigation controller might not be the best approach. However it totally depends on your use case.